# PHP invoice number with alpha numeric increment

Tags: php

The invoice number looks like this **INV{Year}{Month}-1A** Ex: **INV202201-1A**

The suffix 1A's numerical value can only go up to 9. Then the Alphabet should change to B, then the numerical value again goes to 9B then has to change to C & so on. Also when the month changes the prefix should change back to 1A. I've already tried adding all alphabets to an array but I can't seem to figure it out.

I would really appreciate it if someone can point me out the right logic for this.

Comment: How are year, month, and suffix handled? ... is 9C the last suffix, or how high can the last letter go?

Comment: Hi Paul, up to 9Z.  `date('Y') date('m')`

Comment: Ok, but then how to know that the month has changed, and what if invoices get to 9Z before the month ends?

Comment: I was thinking of storing the last date & month used while generating the last code in a table checking them against the current month & year when generating the new code. It won't actually go to 9Z as there's a limit for invoices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### The total of `1A` to `9Z` is `234`.

The data for `$usedPostfix` should be from the database or stored somewhere else.

```
$usedPostfix = array(
    "202112" => 220,
    "202201" => 10,
    "202202" => 0,
);
```

This is where we find the unused postfix to be returned.

```
$date =  date_format(new DateTime(), 'Ym');

function getInvoice($counter, $date)
{
    foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
            if ($counter > 0) {
                $counter--;
                continue;
            }
            return "INV" . $date . "-" . $i . $char;
        }
    }
}
```

> `$date` is using `Ym` format. (e.g: 202201)

Examples:

Using `$date`

```
echo getInvoice($usedPostfix[$date], $date); // OUTPUT: INV202201-2B
```

Using custom `$date` (* for example purpose)

```
echo getInvoice($usedPostfix["202112"], $date); // OUTPUT: INV202201-5Y

echo getInvoice($usedPostfix["202202"], $date); // OUTPUT: INV202201-1A
```